# How to manually deploy a ASP.net MVC project on Mac?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, hosting

I'm using **Visual Studio for Mac** which is different to windows version, as I cannot find either 'Server Explorer' or 'Publish' option. So I just upload the project folder to my domain. Apparently it didn't work, I can only see the index of my project folder from my domain. Can anyone give me some suggestions? I'm quite new to this area.

[image]

Comment: It's an ASP.NET Core App?

Comment: No. Just ASP.NET MVC project

Comment: You should not just upload the project folder to your web server. Now you've uploaded uncompiled code. You need to publish locally and then push the published results up. Or if your IDE has the option, publish directly to the web server. Or better yet, use something like Visual Studio Team Services to check out the code, build it, and deploy it for you.

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac only supports .NET Standard, which for the purposes of a web app, necessitates using ASP.NET Core. You can't build something like an MVC 5 app, as that requires libraries that are incompatible with the Mac architecture.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to borrow a windows laptop

Comment: You don't necessarily need a Windows machine. If you use Visual Studio Team Services you'll be able to edit the code locally, then check in your code to source control, and have it do Continuous Integration to deploy your code to a website. Sure, it's not ideal, but depending on what you're trying to do it may be enough.